# Matlab: Draw multiple images in a single axis on various coordinates

Tags: image, matlab, draw

I would like to visualize a unoriented graph, where icons (bitmaps) are placed on nodes and branches stand for lines.

I have a problem to draw multiple images in a single axis on various coordinates. Is there any possibility how to resolve this problem in Matlab?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Use [`subimage`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/subimage.html).

Example (with three admittedly very dull icons...):

```
im1 = randn(20,20,3); %// example icon. MxNx3 (RGB) array. M, N arbitrary
im2 = .5*ones(20,20,3); %// another icon
im3 = .5+.5*rand(20,20,3); %// yet another
hold on
subimage(50,150,im1) %// change 100,300 to desired coordinates
subimage(100,50,im2)
subimage(150,100,im3)
axis([0 200 0 200]) %// set size. By default axes just enclose the subimages
axis equal %// set equal scale in both axes
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about `subimage`.

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I have been looking for.